# Black Screen trying to capture Google Chrome Window and each application uses hardware acceleration

Tags: c++, windows, webrtc, screen-capture, window-handles

I am Using Webrtc Native Module to capture a single window:

```
    webrtc::DesktopCaptureOptions co = webrtc::DesktopCaptureOptions::CreateDefault();
            desktop_capturer = webrtc::DesktopCapturer::CreateWindowCapturer(co);
            desktop_capturer->GetSourceList(&desktop_screens);
            desktop_capturer->SelectSource(desktop_screens[selectedIndex].id);
            desktop_capturer->Start(this);
```

It works fine but for some applications like "Google Chrome" I get black screen and after searching I find that happen to any application which uses "hardware acceleration" and if I disabled the hardware acceleration in "Google Chrome Settings" I can capture its window without getting black screen but I can't do that for each application which uses "hardware acceleration"

And I am tried to implement another window capturer and I got the same issue "Black Image for each application uses hardware acceleration":

```
  void CaptureFrame(int i, System::String ^ title){
RECT rc;
std::string stdTitle = convertToStdString(title);
std::wstring tit = s2ws(stdTitle);
LPCWSTR t = tit.c_str();
HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, t);

if (hwnd == NULL)
{
    return;
}
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rc);

HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(NULL);
HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hbmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen,
    rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
SelectObject(hdc, hbmp);

PrintWindow(hwnd, hdc, PW_CLIENTONLY);


OpenClipboard(NULL);
EmptyClipboard();
SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hbmp);
CloseClipboard();
std::string ind = std::to_string(i);

std::wstring stemp = s2ws(stdTitle + ind + ".jpeg");
LPCWSTR result = stemp.c_str();
CImage image;
image.Attach(hbmp);
image.Save(result, Gdiplus::ImageFormatBMP);


DeleteDC(hdc);
DeleteObject(hbmp);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);}
```

Comment: Google Chrome uses Direct-X for rendering on Windows and can be captured with a Direct-X hook.